# Insufficient space to create volume snapshot in CentOs

Tags: centos, lvm

I have a `VM` running `Centos8`. I wanted to create snapshots on the root partition.

My disk has 100 GB, which I hadn't partitioned initially, this was not conducive to creating partition snapshots.

Following this I reinstalled `CentOs`, but partitioned the disk into several partitions, which eventually looked like this -

```
[root@my-system ~]# lsblk -a
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                8:0    0  100G  0 disk
├─sda1             8:1    0  1.9G  0 part /boot
└─sda2             8:2    0 58.2G  0 part
  ├─PV--LVM-root 253:0    0   28G  0 lvm  /
  ├─PV--LVM-swap 253:1    0  4.2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─PV--LVM-home 253:2    0 23.3G  0 lvm  /home
  └─PV--LVM-TMP  253:3    0  2.8G  0 lvm  /TMP
sr0               11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

Some 39 GB of disk space was unallocated.

A `vgs` command yielded the following -

```
[root@my-system ~]# vgs
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  PV-LVM   1   4   0 wz--n- <58.22g 4.00m
```

`lvs` the following -

```
[root@my-system ~]# lvs
  LV   VG     Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  TMP  PV-LVM -wi-ao----  <2.80g
  home PV-LVM -wi-ao---- <23.29g
  root PV-LVM -wi-ao----  27.94g
  swap PV-LVM -wi-ao----   4.19g
```

and 'vgdisplay` the following -

```
[root@my-system ~]# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               PV-LVM
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  5
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                4
  Open LV               4
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <58.22 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              14904
  Alloc PE / Size       14903 / 58.21 GiB
  **Free  PE / Size       1 / 4.00 MiB**
  VG UUID               RnIMct-UZXY-F5Tc-maC3-1of5-tFmZ-cLZFH8
```

For some reason, the `Free PE / Size` remains resolutely at 1 / 400MiB

I imagined this problem may be removed if I extend this `lvm`, so I used a guide, https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-increase-the-size-of-a-linux-lvm-by-expanding-the-virtual-machine-disk/ and extended the `/dev/mapper/PV--LVM-root` by 39 GB, and it became 67 GB, with `sda3`.

```
[root@my-system ~]# lsblk
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                8:0    0  100G  0 disk
├─sda1             8:1    0  1.9G  0 part /boot
├─sda2             8:2    0 58.2G  0 part
│ ├─PV--LVM-root 253:0    0 67.9G  0 lvm  /
│ ├─PV--LVM-swap 253:1    0  4.2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
│ ├─PV--LVM-home 253:2    0 23.3G  0 lvm  /home
│ └─PV--LVM-TMP  253:3    0  2.8G  0 lvm  /TMP
└─sda3             8:3    0 39.9G  0 part
  └─PV--LVM-root 253:0    0 67.9G  0 lvm  /
sr0               11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

Notice the `PV--LVM-root` in `sda2` and `sda3`.

Unfortunately, `lvcreate` still fails.

```
[root@my-system ~]# lvcreate -s PV-LVM/root -n root_snapshot_22042020 -L 16G
  Volume group "PV-LVM" has insufficient free space (1 extents): 4096 required.

[root@my-system ~]# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               PV-LVM
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  7
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                4
  Open LV               4
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               <98.13 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              25121
  Alloc PE / Size       25120 / 98.12 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       1 / 4.00 MiB
  VG UUID               RnIMct-UZXY-F5Tc-maC3-1of5-tFmZ-cLZFH8
```

I ended with -

```
[root@my-system ~]# resize2fs /dev/mapper/PV--LVM-root
resize2fs 1.44.3 (10-July-2018)
Filesystem at /dev/mapper/PV--LVM-root is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 4, new_desc_blocks = 9
The filesystem on /dev/mapper/PV--LVM-root is now 17786880 (4k) blocks long.
```

Not sure what to do now. I haven't worked on Linux or disk partitions much. All disks are `ext4` file system...For some reason, even though I "increased" the root `lvm`, it still seems I haven't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You successfully extended the LVM volume group (i.e. the steps in your guide up to and including the `vgextend` command), but then you used up the new space by also extending the `LVM-root` logical volume, using up the new space.

You should have stopped after the `vgextend` step, then you would have had free PEs in your volume group, usable for LVM-level snapshots.

Unfortunately you cannot shrink an `ext4` filesystem on-line, and it's your root filesystem so you cannot just unmount it, so you would need to boot from some live Linux boot media, activate the volume group (`vgchange -ay`) and then shrink the filesystem inside the LV with:

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/PV--LVM-root 29G
```

Then (and only then) you can shrink the LV. If you specify the sizes in gigabytes, it will be safer to specify the new size of the LV as a bit bigger than what you shrunk the filesystem into, to avoid chopping off the tail end of the filesystem because of a rounding error.

(At this point, you can boot back into the CentOS proper, if you wish.)

To shrink the LV to 30G:

```
lvreduce -L 30G /dev/mapper/PV--LVM-root
```

To match the size of the filesystem exactly to the new size of the LV:

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/PV--LVM-root
```

(If this command extends the filesystem just a little bit, you know you did the shrinking step correctly.)

After this, you should have about 38G available in the VG for any combination of snapshots, LV extensions and/or new LVs.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for the explanation. I'd like to know more about the disk partitioning and layouts on Linux, would you have any suggestions? And is there a way to reverse what I did, or am I stuck with adding more disk space to try it out?

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: Thank you.. Appreciate it.